# How do I change the colour of static cells inside an embedded TableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, uicontainerview

I have a view set up (more or less) like this:

-- ViewController

--- ScrollView

--- ContentView

---- ContainerView

-----> TableViewController with ***static cells*** embedded inside the ContainerView

Each view has a matching outlet.

I have configured my background to a nice image that I want to show through all the controls on the page, including the embedded TableViewController.

I've referenced the table like this:

```
UIView *theTableView = self.contentView.subviews[0];
```

and tried to set the colour of the table to clear like this (to make it see-through):

```
theTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But this doesn't work because I think it's the cells' colour I need to change.

How can I reference the embedded table's cells in order to change the colour of the cells' background to clearColor programmatically in my situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the table view's delegate and respond to `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = self.contentView.subviews[0]; // use a property UITableView *tableView
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView != self.tableView) return;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

This will work for both static and dynamic table views.

Comment: Wait, hold on.  In my .h file for my main view, I put `<UITableViewDelegate>` after the @interface declaration.  Then I declared the tableView property as you indicated I should, like this:  `@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *optionsTableView;` Then I used the exact code you've shown here.  BUT...I'm getting an error on run.  It stops at the `self.tableView.delegate = self;` line with the following error:  _-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c87d10_

Comment: Is it because `self.tableView = self.contentView.subviews[0];` is returning some NSView and not the actual table view?  Remember, this is an embedded NSTableViewController (because I needed static cell ability).  When I test this with an ivar set to the `segue.destinationViewController` for the embedded tableViewController (in the prepareForSegue method) it returns something different: a UITableViewController.  Thoughts?

Comment: I solved it!  The following code from your example above should be changed from: UIView `*theTableView = self.contentView.subviews[0];` to `UIView *theTableView = self.containerView.subviews[0];`.  Now my reference works and I can change the table cell colours to any colour...except see-through (clearColor keeps the cells white...must be that the table background isn't clear...next thing to fix.)  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I suppose there are views in your view hirachy that still have a white background, just go through your storyboard and set the background colors to clear. Also, you can mark your question answered ;)